# CodeCampServer don't input any logging from NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, logging

Are you ever succeed input NHibernate logging using CodeCampServer architecture?

I read [this](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx) and I did everything that I can. Maybe there is know problem in this architecture.

I using `Infrastructure.NHibernate.DataAccess.Bases.Logger.EnsureInitialized();`
to initialize log4net. here the code:

```
public class DependencyRegistrar
{
    private static bool _dependenciesRegistered;

    private static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.Scan(y =>
                                                {
                                                    y.AssemblyContainingType<DependencyRegistry>();
                                                    y.AssemblyContainingType<NaakRegistry>();
                                                    y.LookForRegistries();
                                                    y.AddAllTypesOf<IRequiresConfigurationOnStartup>();
                                                }));
        new InitiailizeDefaultFactories().Configure();
    }

    private static readonly object sync = new object();

    internal void ConfigureOnStartup()
    {
        Infrastructure.NHibernate.DataAccess.Bases.Logger.EnsureInitialized();

        RegisterDependencies();
        var dependenciesToInitialized = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IRequiresConfigurationOnStartup>();
        foreach (var dependency in dependenciesToInitialized)
        {
            dependency.Configure();
        }
    }
    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>();
    }

    public static object Resolve(Type modelType)
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(modelType);
    }

    public static bool Registered(Type type)
    {
        EnsureDependenciesRegistered();
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(type) != null;
    }

    public static void EnsureDependenciesRegistered()
    {
        if (!_dependenciesRegistered)
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                if (!_dependenciesRegistered)
                {
                    RegisterDependencies();
                    _dependenciesRegistered = true;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I see the logging files, I can't delete them when the app run, so I know they are generated. in addition, when I log for test, the log **are** input. For example, this code do input log.

```
    Bases.Logger.Debug(this, "Debug test!")
```

So, do CodeCampServer have a architecture problem with log4net?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Accidentally found solution by replacing the reference forlog4net.dll to the on that come with NHibernate bins, instead the own log4net.

Wired, but I have logs... :)

Answer (score -1):

The post looks correct to me.
Are you sure you added the necessary assembly level attribute?

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

If this won't work maybe you should try:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

for example in your Application_Start of Global.asax.
If this won't work please post your example code.

Comment: The Logwrapper you are using ignores the configuration within your App.config. So can you post the Log4Net.config file that is used by this logger?
http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/source/browse/trunk/src/Infrastructure/DataAccess/Bases/Logger.cs?r=1033

Comment: The Default Log4net.config that is used sets NHibernate logging to FATAL. See here: http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/source/browse/trunk/src/Log4Net.config?r=1033

Comment: The priority is in Debug mode. The problem is not in the Log4Net.config file as the file was generated.